# Accessing Secondary Variables

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
for x in `cat /var/www/vhosts/example.com/statistics/logs/access_log.processed | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk {'if ($1 > 2000) print $2'}`; 
do
    #Works        
    printf "$x"     

    #Does not work
    printf "$1"
done
```

I am trying to block IP addresses that have attempted more than 2000 requests. Actually above code is combination of 2 sections.

First,

```
cat /var/www/vhosts/example.com/statistics/logs/access_log.processed | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

I gather, sort and count the all IP addresses. Below is an example result

```
4565 8.8.8.8
3245 7.7.7.7
```

Then I iterate over each result and check if the attempt number is over 2000.

```
awk {'if ($1 > 2000) print $2'}
```

`$1` is attempt number and `$2` is IP.

So `$2` is saved as `$x` and can be used inside for loop. But how can I also use `$1` inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop instead of a `for`, and emit multiple columns from `awk`.

```
while read x y; do
  echo $y $x
done << EOF
example one
example two
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `bash` and `awk` have its own variables set. `$1` in `awk` differs form `$1` in `bash` both by meaning and value. In your case you may pass `"$1 $2"` array to `$x` and then split it inside a loop

```
for x in `cat /var/www/vhosts/example.com/statistics/logs/access_log.processed | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk {'if ($1 > 2000) print $1, $2'}`; do  
  IFS=" " read first second <<< "$x"
  #now $first=$1, $second=$2  
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What is the purpose of IFS please? Is it just a dummy to let splitting the variables?

Comment: Oh I just figured out `do` runs twice, and it is not possible to have $first and $second at the same run. So this becomes useless for my case.

Comment: What means 'do runs twice'?

Comment: When the script enters in "do", first it puts the value into $first variable and $second variable is empty somehow. Then it enters "do" again and this time $first is empty and $second variable gets value. So $first and $second variables do not have connection somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Why re-invent the wheel when [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) can already do what you want (and a lot more)?

With `fail2ban`, you can make a custom rule that matches any request to a given web site (or all hosted web sites), and set the `maxretry` for that rule to 2000.

You can also set the `bantime` for that rule to whatever you want (e.g. `bantime=86400` to block that IP for a day).

By default, it will also log every block and un-block action, e.g. in `/var/log/fail2ban.log`.

BTW, You may want to re-think your goal.  2000 requests from a single IP is not really a lot of requests, especially if each "page" you serve contains numerous images, css files, javascript files, etc.  Or if that IP address is a proxy (e.g. running `squid`) for dozens or hundreds of machines on a school or corporate network.  or for an ISP.

Comment: Thanks. Fail2ban I think use too much resource and is not good at searching for patterns like in my case. I use CDN and all assets are loaded from CDN. So users only come to my site for web pages. Therefore if there are 2000 page requests, I block them no matter what. Especially they are click bombs generally.